# $z_0$ be a removable singularity of f . Show that $z_0$ is then a removable singularity of exp ( f ) .

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

$z_0$   be a removable singularity of f . Show that  $z_0$  is then a removable singularity of exp ( f ) .

Comment: A repetition of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719449/z-0-be-an-isolated-singularity-of-f-show-that-z-0-is-then-an-isolated-sing

Answer (score 0):

Since $z_0 $is a removable singularity of$ f$ that means that the Laurent series of $f$ about$ z_0$ is a Taylor series that is
$f=c_0+c_1(z-z_0)+....$
since$ e^f=1+f+\frac{f^2}{2}+....$
Clearly $z_0$ also a removable singularity of $ e^f$.